# How can you emplace_back the wrong type?

Tags: c++

I have a vector of doubles. But I had a typo

I intended to write this:

```
std::vector<double> timestamp;
```

But I wrote this instead:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> timestamp;
```

However, this compiles

```
timestamp.emplace_back(a_double_timestamp)
```

I am emplacing back a `double` into a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. `double` is not `std::vector<double>`

Comment: Maybe by calling a nimplicit constructor of `std::vector<double>` ? I know that `std::vector<double>{1.0}` is a valid way of defining a vector

Comment: Because [it takes `Args&&...`, not `T`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: `emplace_back` is used to construct a new element using the given arguments. So if you can write `std::vector<double> X{a_double_timestamp}` it's normal that `emplace_back(a_double_timestamp)` works. You might be thinking of [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double` is implicitly converted to `size_type`, acting as a parameter to [the vector constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) :

```
explicit vector( size_type count );
```

Therefore, if you pass `2.3`, the vector created has size `static_cast<std::vector<double>::size_type>(2.3) == 2`.

`std::vector<double> v{2.3}` also compiles without any warning.

Comment: This means I ended up initializing a massive vector. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any warnings? MSVC gives warning

> 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'const unsigned __int64',
>   possible loss of data

though GCC HEAD is silent.

What happens here is that `explicit vector( size_type count );` constructor for your internal vector is called, with automatic conversion from double to `size_type`

Answer (score 0):

I stepped through the code to see what was happening, and what I am seeing (in Visual Studio 2017 anyway) is that the following constructor is being called:

`vector(_CRT_GUARDOVERFLOW const size_type _Count, const _Alloc& _Al = _Alloc())`

... which seems to imply that the double was implicitly converted to a size_type (I used a double of 12.3 in my test, and the debugger is telling me _Count is 12). `_Al` has a default value, so the constructor matches.

Comment: Correct. Be careful what you ask a c++ compiler to do. It will obey the rules to the letter of the standard. A double will undergo a narrowing conversion to a long integer in order to satisfy the argument matching of function overload selection.